# jQuery Ajax fallback return

Tags: jquery

I have a JavaScript function inside which I use jQuery .post,
and I wanted to return a boolean in the fallback:

```
function is_available() {
    $.post('ajax', {
        action: 'mail'
    }, function(data) {
        if ($.trim(data) == 'NO_ERROR') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

but the function returns undefinied.
How could I return that boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those `return` statements you currently have don't run until later, you need to call any code that relies on the data from the callback, for example:

```
function check_available() {
  $.post('ajax', {
    action: 'mail'
  }, function(data) {
    myNextFunction($.trim(data) == 'NO_ERROR');
  });
}
function myNextFunction(isAvailable) {
  //do something, this runs after the AJAX request completes the check
}
```

So instead of treating is synchronosuly with a `return` statement, treat the code path as asynchronous, and kickoff whatever code needs that "is available" value from the callback of [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), it'll execute when the server request comes back and that boolean you need is ready to use.

Currently it's returning `undefined` because that callback function happens *later* (after your current code trying to use the value).